How to programmatically change the host of JmsInboundGateway during runtime?
I tried this, however after after restarting the gateway, it stops consuming any new messages.
 SolConnectionFactory connFactory =
          (SolConnectionFactory) msgListenerContainer.getConnectionFactory();

        jmsInboundGateway.stop();
        connFactory.setHost(newInboundHost);
        jmsInboundGateway.start();
  


Does it start consuming messages again if newInboundHost is the same as the old one?

Nope. I did this:

Start up with host A (able to consume).
Switch to host B (invalid host, connection fails)
-Switch to host A ( not able to consume)

